# Why does an anonymous function have access to a variable from the function it is defined in?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

I'm trying to get my head around jQuery and JavaScript objects and functions and grasp how `this` works and where it points to.

Please can someone explain why [this](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/14/how-to-use-the-self-with-object-oriented-javascript-and-closures/) works.

```
Cat.prototype.meowLater = function() {
    var self = this;
    window.setTimeout(
        function() {
            self.meow();
        }
        , 1000);
}
```

The bit I'm interested in and confused by is why the variable `self` can actually be accessed in the anonymous function that's called by the timer. I thought that because `self` is declared in another function that it would be local and only accessible to that function.

Comment: Why shouldn't that work? Self is a local variable but the timer function call is local too, inside the mewlater method.

Comment: I've never really used anonymous functions before which is why I'm a bit confused. Does this mean then that any anonymous function has access to all the variables that have been set in the function that loaded it (and any global ones)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inner functions can use variables available to outer functions.

Here,

```
Cat.prototype.meowLater = function() {
    // I create the variable self that refers to the this (the current object)
    var self = this;

    // I create a timeout that calls the self.meow function within an anonymous function
    /*** NOTE : You don’t always have to create an anonymous function it’s just that in
        this case, it is required ***/
    window.setTimeout(
        function() {
            self.meow();
        }
        , 1000);
}
```

Since, the `setTimeout` is inner function of `Cat.prototype.meowLater`, `self` available to `setTimeout`.

Also,

we are not using `this.meow()` here, because `this` refers to current object , thus to `window` in `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Thanks. It all makes a lot more sense now!

Why does `setTimeout` have to be attached to something and what does it achieve?

Comment: `setTimeout` calls a function after a fixed time. In this example `self.meow();` will be called after `1000 micro seconds`.

Mark as answer, if this helps you :)

Comment: I understand that bit. My question is that is there a difference between `setTimeout(...)` and `window.setTimeout(...)`? Why does `setTimeout` have to be 'linked' (I'm not sure what the technical word is) to something?

Comment: It's the same thing, this only assures that setTimeout() function is called and not some other function that may have the same name as this one.

Comment: Thanks. If you call any function without the handle(?) does it always default to `window` then (unless there's another with the same name)?

Comment: `setTimeout();` is a function of `window` object. So, `window.setTimeout();`. This is the right way. But, since `window` object is available in environment, its not necessary to add `window`. Its optional.

Comment: More about the nested functions can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 2):

A function inherits variables from the parent scope (unless masked by another variable with the same name and of narrower scope).

Since the anonymous function is defined inside the function to which `self` is scoped, it has access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has nested scopes, so a function inside of another function inherits all the variables from the outer function (it's still in scope). When you use async functions (`setTimeout` in this case) the variable `self` will refer to the scoped self variable, which is `this` (a Cat instance), but `this` will be window.

Hopefully that helps, it's something that takes some time to get used to.